# Python DB Update with SQLAlchemy + posgtresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Here is my code for updating postgresql DB table via sqlalchemy orm:

```
db_car_record = session.query(CarsTable).update({CarsTable.CarId : 37805,
                                                   CarsTable.AuctionId : 879})

session.commit()
```

I receive the duplicate key error. Do you have any idea?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_carstable_CarId"
DETAIL:  Key ("CarId")=(37805) already exists.
 [SQL: 'UPDATE carstable SET "AuctionId"=%(AuctionId)s, "CarId"=%(CarId)s,
updated_on=%(updated_on)s'] [parameters: {'updated_on': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 12, 3, 49, 23, 115733), 'CarId': 37805, 'AuctionId': 879}]
```

Comment: You already have a row in the db with `CarId` 37805. I'm not sure how to make that any clearer.

Comment: You'll want to move the id to a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the AuctionId of the car that has a CarId of 37805?

```
car_to_change = session.query(CarsTable).filter(CarsTable.CarId==37805).first()
car_to_change.AuctionId = 879
session.commit()
```

You can also do:

```
# Notice difference between `filter` and `filter_by`
car_to_change = session.query(CarsTable).filter_by(CarId=37805).first()
car_to_change.AuctionId = 879
session.commit()
```

Here's a tutorial that'll get you started: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html